# AngularJS to display one section in Italic

Tags: angularjs

Hi i'm creating a Harvard Reference Generator using AngularJS ive got it working perfectly, i can get it to create the full reference however i need one section to be styled in italics, the information is captured using a form. I require a little help with the output.

Current Output Code:

```
{{
book_author+"&nbsp;"+book_multiple_authors+"&nbsp;("+book_year+").&nbsp;
"+book_title+".
&nbsp;
"+book_place+":
&nbsp;
"+book_publisher+".
&nbsp;
"+ book_edition
}}.
```

What i need is for one section "book_title" to be shown in italics
I have tried:

```
{{
book_author+"&nbsp;"+book_multiple_authors+"&nbsp;("+book_year+").&nbsp;
<i>"+book_title+".</i>
&nbsp;
"+book_place+":
&nbsp;
"+book_publisher+".
&nbsp;
"+ book_edition
}}.
```

```
{{
book_author+"&nbsp;"+book_multiple_authors+"&nbsp;("+book_year+").&nbsp;
"+<i>book_title</i>+".
&nbsp;
"+book_place+":
&nbsp;
"+book_publisher+".
&nbsp;
"+ book_edition
}}.
```

```
{{
book_author+"&nbsp;"+book_multiple_authors+"&nbsp;("+book_year+").&nbsp;
"<i>+book_title+</i>".
&nbsp;
"+book_place+":
&nbsp;
"+book_publisher+".
&nbsp;
"+ book_edition
}}.
```

Nothing seems to work, i cant find any further reference to formatting the angularjs output specific to one section.  What am i missing, any help would be greatly appreciated.  That You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To have HTML rendered within ng expressions, you need to use `ngSanitize` or [`$sce`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$sce) dependency. Else, HTML will be rendered as string inside your expressions.

In your case, you can simplify it by breaking it down to multiple elements:

```
<span ng-bind="book_author"></span> 
<span ng-bind="book_multiple_authors"></span>
<span ng-bind="book_year"></span>

<i>
  <span ng-bind="book_title"></span>
</i>

<span ng-bind="book_place"></span>
<span ng-bind="book_publisher"></span>
<span ng-bind="book_edition"></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Code between double curly braces in AngularJS is meant to be JavaScript, so it can't contain HTML tags. The way around it would be along these lines:

```
{{book_author+"&nbsp;"+book_multiple_authors
+"&nbsp;("+book_year+").&nbsp";}}
<i>{{book_title}}</i>
{{"&nbsp;"+book_place+":&nbsp;"+book_publisher
+".&nbsp;"+book_edition;}}
```

Let me know if this works for you, if not we can try CSS instead to render text in italics.

Best wishes,
Lukasz